# Get a less intimidating facebook authentication permission list

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication

My Facebook app's authentication dialog says:

> [Application name] would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address.

I don't want or need to read the user's friend list, and this seems like it might put people off using it. I only use the app for authentication, with just the [`email` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/).

When I [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token) the token, it shows only `email` in the scopes field. Yet when I use that token in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me?fields=friends), it does show me a list of friends. I assume the friend list is included by default now, but I'm hoping it can still be disabled somehow.

How can I get the friends list out of the authentication dialog, or else explain that I won't use that information? This [has been asked before](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8716182/making-auth-dialog-less-intimidating), but that answer no longer applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but you cannot. Quoting from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/),

> When a user logs into your app and you request no additional permissions, the app will have access to only the user's public profile and friend list.

These permissions will be by default added to your application, what you do of this is your choice.

Comment: Damn. Any way to communicate what I will/won't do with that data in the authentication dialog?

Comment: You can set a description in your app detail settings. (I don’t know of the top of my head which one of the fields will show up on the first page of the login dialog, description or the long description – just give it a try.)

Comment: @CBroe There's an `Explanation for Permissions` field under `App Details` which says `If you ask for any extended permissions, provide an explanation for how your app plans to use them`. So it looks like that only shows up when you ask for extended permissions. I've filled out all the description fields too, but they don't show up anywhere in the auth dialog.

Comment: According to the screenshots on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ (hardly recognizable) it should show some of these. Are you sure you waited long enough for FB to have your new app details settings updated on all servers?

Comment: Fairly sure, it's been an hour now and the auth dialog hasn't changed. Those screenshots don't look anything like the current auth dialogs either, so I think they're out of date too.